# will the getMethod of a servlet be executed in such scenario?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

if i have a hyperlink as follows :

```
<a href="helloServletaction=details?id=55" onclick="return false;"></a>
```

with such a hypelink would the getMethod still be executed of the helloServlet since there is the `return false;`?

Comment: Seems a ludicrously simple thing to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If javascript is enabled in the browser, then no. `return false;` cancels following the anchor. An HTTP request will not be sent.